# Which Salesforce licenses can use Ideas? Specifically, can a Salesforce Platform license see and create Ideas?

Tags: licenses, ideas

I'm trying to determine which Salesforce licenses can use "Ideas" but all the documentation I've found primarily talks about Cases and CRM.  Which license types can actually use Ideas?